# Why does my Rmarkdown document does not show any unicode characters when knitting to pdf?

Tags: r, unicode, r-markdown

Somehow I can't get the unicode symbols (representing different p-values) to print when knitting to pdf. When I use the same code but print to html everything works fine? What am I doing wrong here?

---

````
output:
html_document:
df_print: paged
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---



```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,warning=FALSE)

library("readxl")
library("knitr")
library("kableExtra")
library("dplyr")
library("reshape2")


```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis',warning=FALSE}
    
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                  spider = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.1, 0.01,0.01),
                  beetle = c(0.09, 0.01, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1))

 
```



```{r table, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

df1[df1 == 0.05] <- "&#8857;"
df1[df1 == 0.09] <- "&#8413;"
df1[df1 == 0.01] <- "&#9210;"
df1[df1 == 0.1]  <- "&#821;"


kable(df1,"markdown",align="c",bookmarks=T)


```
````

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite how you enter unicode characters in R source, use the \U escape instead:

```r
cat("This is chinese: \U8857\n")
```

Outputs `This is chinese: 街`

Furthermore, R and most modern text editors handle unicode just fine, you could likely go ahead and just use the unicode characters in the source for your own use or you know that whomever will run the source is ok with it.

Furthermore you need a font that actually has glyphs for these characters, *Noto Sans CJK SC* is a good candidate unlessd you know you have others installed.

Your markup could look like this then:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Noto Sans CJK SC
---



```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,warning=FALSE)

library("readxl")
library("knitr")
library("kableExtra")
library("dplyr")
library("reshape2")


```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis',warning=FALSE}

df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                  spider = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.1, 0.01,0.01),
                  beetle = c(0.09, 0.01, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1))


```



```{r table, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

## df1[df1 == 0.05] <- "街"
## df1[df1 == 0.09] <- "萓"
## df1[df1 == 0.01] <- "鈐"
## df1[df1 == 0.1]  <- "ࠡ"
df1[df1 == 0.05] <- "\U8857"
df1[df1 == 0.09] <- "\U8413"
df1[df1 == 0.01] <- "\U9210"
df1[df1 == 0.1]  <- "\U821"

kable(df1,"markdown",align="c",bookmarks=T)


```
````

The table in the pdf file looks like this, so not perfect, but almost there:

[image: unicode table]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. The  \U escape code for my symbols just gives me the plain code in my pdf. And how do I get the "Noto Sans CJK SC " font? I know that this font is good for chinese characters, but how about other symbols?

Comment: On my linux system (Fedora) I get that font from this package: `google-noto-sans-cjk-ttc-fonts`. For windows, there seems to be an install page here: https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/

Comment: @Sirius:  Windows R doesn't handle Unicode well, which might mean Conny can't use your code even with the appropriate font installed.  There are efforts to fix this, but they aren't released yet.  See https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2021/03/12/windows/utf-8-toolchain-and-cran-package-checks/index.html .

Comment: It's really weird that `\U` doesn't work. can you run `rmarkdown::render( "yourfile.Rmd", clean=FALSE )` and inspect all the intermediate files, particularly yourfile.utf8.md

Comment: @user2554330: yes, I'm using Windows - does this mean I have to find different ways to turn my data into a nice looking table? I just spent 2 days on it..grrrr....

Comment: @Conny:  You could try the experimental build of R that I linked to, or run your code in Linux (which can be done in a VM within Windows).  I don't know any easy solutions.